# How to insert permissions for files stored in Google Drive to share it with people in my domain

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I have a GSuite account. We have some files stored on Google Drive from a web application. I know that, I can add permission 'Anyone with the link' to files by setting role 'reader' and type 'anyone' with 'permissions' resource of Google Drive API. But, I want to add permissions for files stored in Google Drive to access it only to people in my domain with the help of Google Client library (PHP library). Can you please help me out?

I have a PHP function to insert permission for a file with file ID

```
function insertPermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role) {
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setType($type);
    $newPermission->setRole($role);
    $newPermission->setWithLink(true);
    try {
        return $service->permissions->insert($fileId, $newPermission);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) Creates a permission for a file or Team Drive.

> type   string  The type of the grantee. Valid values are:
>
> - user
> - group
> - **domain**
> - anyone

Background info a normal drive account the type will be `"type": "user",`  You should set the type to domain.

There is some Optional Properties you can send with the request i sugest adding.

> domain The domain to which this permission refers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Setting 'type' to 'domain' and 'value' to my domain worked for me.